# In twig how to pass a path function his argument from a var sent from a controller in Symfony

Tags: symfony, path, routes, twig

I need create a link in a twig template of a var sent from a controller

```
<a href=" {{path('main_catcliente_gestion')}} " class="btn btn-default"> return </a>
```

but in this case I need that 'main_catcliente_gestion' redirect to a variable route

I send to the twing a variable called "route" and in it store te nombre of a route I do this in this maner:

```
<a href=" {{path('{{route}}')}} " class="btn btn-default"> return </a>
```

an in this manner too:

```
<a href=" {{path('route')}} " class="btn btn-default"> return </a>
```

but both returns me a error.
how i do it?

Comment: `{{path(route)}}`

Comment: yeah it works, I must be try it too

Comment: Or if you want to use the [string interpolation](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#string-interpolation) : `{{ path("#{route}") }}` (makes no sense here, but good to know)